# Does truly accidental degeneracies exist anywhere in quantum systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

I was wondering whether there are instances of truly accidental degeneracy in physics i.e., degeneracies that cannot be linked with some symmetry of the system/Hamiltonian. I have the following example in mind. Consider the energy of a 2D box with sides $L$ and $2L$. Then the energy is $$E=\frac{\pi\hbar^2}{4L^2}\left(4n_x^2+n_y^2\right).$$ Note that the states with quantum numbers $n_x=2$, $n_y=2$ and $n_x=1$, $n_y=4$ have the same energy i.e., degenerate. But I am not sure if this provides an example of a truly accidental degeneracy. If not, does anyone know about the occurrence of truly accidental degeneracies?

Comment: There are certainly examples. If you consider a box of water, many of the vibrational modes may become accidentally degenerate as the various molecules wiggle about. This is about as “random” as it gets, and certainly has nothing to do with any symmetry since the molecules are wriggling about at random.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean "truly accidental". Whenever your theory has two degenerate states $|0 \rangle$ and $|1 \rangle$, you can simply *define* an operator that maps between them,
$$Q |0 \rangle = |1 \rangle, \qquad Q |1 \rangle = |0 \rangle$$
and leaves all other states unaffected. Then by construction, $Q$ commutes with the Hamiltonian, so it's a symmetry of the system. In this trivial sense, any degeneracy can be explained by a symmetry.

However, defining $Q$ doesn't tell us anything we didn't already know. When we say a degeneracy is "explained" by a symmetry, we mean that $Q$ isn't some contrived operator made up after the fact, but rather some preexisting thing with an intuitive physical interpretation. In that stricter sense, degeneracies really can be truly accidental, with no symmetry-based explanation whatsoever. They can arise either from pure luck, or from some underlying structure which implements a tuning in the Hamiltonian. Or perhaps they arise from an even deeper symmetry that people have missed.

One concrete example of this in the Standard Model is the degeneracy of the spin states of the neutron in an electric field, i.e. the vanishing of the neutron electric dipole moment. This cannot be explained by parity and/or charge conjugation, since those aren't symmetries of the Standard Model. It arises from the fact that the $\bar{\theta}$ parameter in the Standard Model Lagrangian is zero up to experimental uncertainty, and the reason is an active field of research. People debate whether it arises from a tuning implemented over cosmological time (i.e. by a relaxing axion field) or as a consequence of a parity-like symmetry in an extension of the Standard Model, or something else.

Comment: Nice! Do you have any examples from nonrelativistic quantum mechanics? What do you think about the example I gave?